# SSIS data transfer adding characters (SQL Server to Postgres)

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, greenplum

I've created an SSIS package that takes geography data out of a SQL Server database and copies it to a geometry column in a `Greenplum` Postgres database.

I'm doing it in a roundabout way because of weird errors with the PGNP driver when trying it the normal way. So what I'm doing is using `GeogColumn.STAsText()` on the SQL Server source and inserting that into a text column in the `Greenplum` database, then running a task that updates the geometry column in the `Greenplum` table using the newly inserted text, which should e.g. look like `POLYGON(-85 42, -86 43)`.

The problem is that **\\000** is getting added after each character and then the update won't work.  Here's what it looks like:

Source
[image]

Destination

[image]

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: `\000` appears to be the NULL character which would terminate a string from my half-remembered C days. That data is probably tagged as DT_IMAGE in the SSIS metadata, yeah? In which case, a data viewer isn't going to be use. I pinged a friend who works with GIS data and has done so within SSIS, hopefully he can be of help.

Comment: The source and destination are both DT_NTEXT in SSIS, I've checked many times.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wonder if that's the issue. I wonder if the nvarchar(max) data from [STAsText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933970.aspx) is getting a line terminator in it for some reason. Or that it's getting bollixed up in the transfer. If you tried an explicit cast to an image type, would that work or make any difference. Thus `CAST(GeogColumn.STAsText() AS image) AS imgColumn` I wonder if that would deal with NUL better.

Comment: When I try that SSIS says "Explicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to image is not allowed."

Comment: Trying to get a minimum reproduction, at least from SQL Server into SSIS. Don't have any Postgres to talk to here, or anywhere. This seems to work to make it binary. My brain meant varbinary(max) but my fingers did not comply. `SELECT CAST(CAST(geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0),(2 2, 2 1, 1 1, 1 2, 2 2))', 0) AS geometry).STAsText() AS varbinary(max)) AS geo_bin`

Comment: The results were the same when casting as varbinary(max).  Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps try the following(in your TSQL source query):

```
,CAST(geogColumn.STAsText() as varchar(max)) AS WKT_TEXT 
,geogColumn.STAsBinary() AS WKB_IMAGE
```

I would go with the 2nd flavor as it should be slightly more efficient

Not sure what the destination columns need to be on the PG side but i suspect TEXT and IMAGE

Comment: BTW, I'm using the PGNP driver and I had to NOT use the fast load option to get it to work.  Thanks.